# css selector not selecting

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to select all paragraph which is followed by some anchor. The way am using is not working

```
p < a { border: solid 1px red; }
```

html

```
<p><a href="#">Link1</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Link1</a></p>
<p>empty para without link</p>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vGR8D/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to select all paragraph which is followed by some anchor.

You can't do that. There is no parent selector in CSS. So you can't select element by it's content.

Comment: Can you please check here for "Wish upon a star" (search for this text)? http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: As the site says: "It could be like this", but it isn't. Can be done using JavaScript (there is an example on page you linked to), but not with pure CSS.

Comment: As I said, it's not possible until CSS4 is implemented in any browser (it's not now)

Comment: @SSS: I would think the subtitle "Wish upon a star" would hint at the fact that that's not actual, real, working CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it wrong:

not

`p < a`

only

`p > a`

Comment: I am trying to select p not anchor

Comment: Ahh my mistake, CSS Selectors Level 4 will support this.

Comment: @Damonsson But not with as easy a syntax as this!